# Rotate wacom tablet in wayland

Tags: wacom

How can I rotate my Wacom Tablet using wayland? I have it rotated 180 degrees. In Windows this is no problem with the Wacom software.

EDIT: Aha it's just theleft handed orientation button in Wacom settings

Comment: Please add more details about the version of Ubuntu you are using, and the model number of your Wacom tablet.